# How to make a method print a method

Tags: java

So I'm getting an error message saying this, and Im not sure what is going on. So any help would be appreciated.

```
1 error found:
File: /Volumes/BRAD'S USB/BonusLab/BonusLab.java  [line: 10]
Error: /Volumes/BRAD'S USB/BonusLab/BonusLab.java:10: cannot find symbol
symbol  : variable array
location: class BonusLab
```

Heres my main:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;
public class BonusLab
{
  public static void main (String[]args) throws IOException
  {
    printName();
    System.out.println("Celsius temperatures read from file: ");
    printWeather(array); ERROR IS RIGHT HERE
    System.out.println("Celsius temperatures with Fahrenheit equivalent: ");

  }//end main
```

This method is pulling numbers from a file
Heres what I have in my method:

```
public static double[] weather() throws IOException{
  Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("weather.txt"));
  int size = input.nextInt();
  double[] array = new double[size];
  for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    array[i] = input.nextDouble();
  }
  return array;
}//end weather
```

This method prints the above method:

```
public static void printWeather() throws IOException{
  double[] array = weather();
  for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
    System.out.print(array[i] + "  " );
}//end printWeather
```

Comment: array is not defined on that line

Comment: Why are you trying to pass array as a parameter in your main?

Comment: Im trying to print 6 numbers from a file I pulled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
printWeather(array); ERROR IS RIGHT HERE
```

to

```
printWeather(); // printWeather() actually calls the weather function and it returns an array.
```

Comment: printweather actually calls weather, and takes no args

Answer (score 0):

Are you supposed to take the array size from the input text file ? 
`int size = input.nextInt();`

I think this is the mistake that you made.

Comment: No, everything works until I tried printing it this way. I have done it the long way, and it works.

Answer (score 0):

array is not defined outside printWeather. As it's out of scope, it can't even compile.

First, define a String that can keep the value returned from printWeather()
Second, remove or modify printName. It's an empty method! It executes nothing.
Third, if you want to add a print method with a specific format, add it to he class containing your weather. Something like:

```
String printAWeather(){
System.out.println(data, format_parameters)
}
```

And execute then

```
myWeather.printAWeather();
```

From what I see you've serious issues with the java grammar.